# Уведомления для сайта php

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, уведомления

Нужно сделать систему уведомлений для пользователей сети на сайте . Текст уведомлений заранее должен составляться администратором. Пожалуйста , подскажите , какими средствами можно это сделать

Comment: Рассчитываете на свои силы, или ищете сторонние сервисы?

Answer (score 1):

Через PushAll. Создаете канал, на сайте на него делаете ссылку - далее через панель управления делаете рассылку или через API гонять запросы из вашей админки.